# Can <input> elements have capital letters and spaces in PHP

Tags: php, forms

Do `<input>` elements in forms need to be a single word, either in totality or using an underscore, or can they have spaces?

```
<input name="This is a name" />

<?php var_dump($_POST['This is a name']); ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They need to be a single word, but can have numbers and underscores.

Comment: Any documentation to back this up?

Answer (score 3):

A form name attribute may contain spaces, but you will find that in PHP the spaces (and periods) are replaced with underscores in the `$_GET` / `$_POST` / `$_REQUEST` arrays:

```
<pre><?php var_dump($_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST); ?></pre>

<form method="get">
    <input name="This is a name" value="This is a value" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

With either "get" or "post" methods, the input will be keyed `This_is_a_name`.

Reference: [PHP: Variables From External Sources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#example-83) (Note below example)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, input in forms should be a single word. They can have underscores or numbers and they can also be Capital letters but there should be no space in the name you specify. Also make sure you don't enter special characters in name.

Answer (score 0):

Space should not be used, as they are replaced by `_`. You can use Underscore instead of space to avoid forceful replacement.